# calling the text file to java

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files, extends

When I run the following code, it only prints the "year\tposition\tname\tMonthlySalary\tAnnualSales\tStockPrice", not the information stored in data.txt. It does not calculate the average2014 and average2015 either. I was using NetBeans for this code and did not see any errors.

data.txt has

2014 Employee Smith,James 2000

2014 Salesman Johnson,Mary 3500 10000

2014 Executive Williams,Robert 2800 25

2015 Employee Jones,Barbara 4000

2015 Salesman Brown,William 3700 5000

2015 Executive Davis,Jennifer 2600 51

2014 Employee Miller,Richard 3900

2014 Salesman Wilson,Susan 4200 7000

2014 Executive Moore,Joseph 1900 65

2015 Employee Taylor,Dorothy 3700

2015 Salesman Anderson,Christopher 3200 15000

2015 Executive Thomas,Nancy 4400 33

```
class Employee{
private String year;
private String name;
private String position;
private double monthlySalary;
public Employee(String year, String position, String name, double monthlySalary){
    this.year = year;
    this.position = position;
    this.name = name;
    this.monthlySalary = monthlySalary;
}
public double annualSalary(){
    return monthlySalary*12;
}
public String toString(){
    return year+"\t"+position+"\t"+name +"\t" + monthlySalary +"\t";
}
}class Salesman extends Employee{
private double annualSales;

public Salesman(String year, String position, String name, double monthlySalary, double annualSales){
    super(year, position, name, monthlySalary);
    this.annualSales = annualSales;
}

public double annualSalary(){
    double commission = this.annualSales*0.2;
    if(commission>20000){
        commission = 20000;
    }
    return super.annualSalary()+commission;
}
public String toString(){
    return super.toString()+annualSalary();
}
}class Executive extends Employee{
private double stockPrice;
public Executive(String year, String position, String name, double monthlySalary, double stockPrice){
    super(year, position, name, monthlySalary);
    this.stockPrice = stockPrice;
}
public double annualSalary(){
    double bonus=0;
    if(this.stockPrice>50){
        bonus = 30000;
    }
    return super.annualSalary() + annualSalary();
}
public String toString(){
    return super.toString()+"\t"+ this.stockPrice+"\n";
}

}

class TestEmployee {
ArrayList<Employee> employee2014 = new ArrayList<Employee>();
ArrayList<Employee> employee2015 = new ArrayList<Employee>();

public void MakeArray(){
    try{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            String year = sc.nextLine();
            String[] data = year.split(" ");
            if(data[0] == "2014"){
                if(data[1].equalsIgnoreCase("Employee")){
                    employee2014.add(new Employee(data[0],data[1],data[2],Double.parseDouble(data[3])));
                }else if(data[1].equalsIgnoreCase("Salesman")){
                    employee2014.add(new Salesman(data[0],data[1],data[2],Double.parseDouble(data[3]),Double.parseDouble(data[4])));                   
                }else if(data[1].equalsIgnoreCase("Executive")){
                    employee2014.add(new Executive(data[0],data[1],data[2],Double.parseDouble(data[3]),Double.parseDouble(data[4])));                    
                }
            }if(data[0] == "2015"){
                if(data[1].equalsIgnoreCase("Employee")){
                    employee2015.add(new Employee("2015",data[1],data[2],Double.parseDouble(data[3])));
                }else if(data[1].equalsIgnoreCase("Salesman")){
                    employee2015.add(new Salesman("2015",data[1],data[2],Double.parseDouble(data[3]),Double.parseDouble(data[4])));                   
                }else if(data[1].equalsIgnoreCase("Executive")){
                    employee2015.add(new Executive("2015",data[1],data[2],Double.parseDouble(data[3]),Double.parseDouble(data[4])));                    
                }
            }
        }    
    }catch(FileNotFoundException nf){
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
}public void Result(){
    double average2014=0;
    double total2014=0;
    double average2015=0;
    double total2015=0;
    System.out.print("Data of 2014:\n"
            + "Year\tPosition\tName\tMonthlySalary\tAnnualSales\tStockPrice");
    for(Employee employee14: employee2014){
        System.out.println(employee14.toString());
        total2014 +=employee14.annualSalary();
    }average2014 = total2014/employee2014.size();
    System.out.print("\nThe average annual salary of 2014 is " + average2014+"\n");
    System.out.println("==================================");

    System.out.print("Data of 2015:\n"
            + "Year\tPosition\tName\tMonthlySalary\tAnnualSales\tStockPrice");
    for(Employee employee15: employee2015){
        System.out.println(employee15.toString());
        total2015 +=employee15.annualSalary();
    }average2015 = total2014/employee2015.size();
    System.out.print("\nThe average annual salary of 2015 is " + average2015+"\n");
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    TestEmployee te = new TestEmployee();
    te.MakeArray();
    te.Result();  
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In the "MakeArray" method (first letter of methods should be in lower case for convention) you should use equals method instead of "==" operator:

```
if(data[0] == "2014") --> if(data[0].equals("2014"))
if(data[0] == "2015") --> if(data[0].equals("2015"))
```

Fix also the annualSalary() (in Executive class) method as follow:

```
public double annualSalary(){
    double bonus=0;
    if(this.stockPrice>50){
        bonus = 30000;
    }
    return super.annualSalary() + bonus;
}
```